# Image events: identical script saves as an RGB JPEG on one Mac, CMYK JPEG on another

Tags: applescript, image-events

Here's the offending code:

```
repeat with this_indd_jpeg in indd_jpeg_list
  set original_name to name of this_indd_jpeg
  set the_small_path to export_path & original_name as string
  set the_large_path to (Large_Folder as string) & original_name as string
  tell application "Image Events"
    launch
    set this_image to open (this_indd_jpeg as alias)
    scale this_image to size target_length_large
    save this_image as JPEG in file the_large_path with icon
    scale this_image to size target_length_small
    save this_image as JPEG in file the_small_path with icon
    close this_image
  end tell              
end repeat
```

The problem is that on one Mac (10.7.5) it saves the JPEGs in RGB (the desired behaviour), and on another (10.6.8) it saves them in CMYK which is definitely undesired.

Is anyone aware of any workarounds or differences between the Image Events versions in 10.6 and 10.7? I'm not certain of any: it's just a stab in the dark.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the difference in image events between 10.7.5 and 10.6.8. But you could try changing the color space with sips:

```
set theImage to quoted form of POSIX path of (the_large_path)
do shell script "/usr/bin/sips -m '/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Generic RGB Profile.icc' " & " " & theImage
```

Comment: Errors everywhere. The most often occurring was `page1.jpg not a valid file - skipping. Error 4: no file was specified`. Any ideas?

Comment: The code is intendeed to be added between end tell and end repeat statements. What's the content of the_large_path at this point?

Comment: Ah, I see. `the_large_path` is `set the_large_path to (Large_Folder as string) & original_name as string`. 
`Large_Folder` is `set Large_Folder to export_path & "Large:" as string`. 
`original_name` is `set original_name to name of this_indd_jpeg`. 
`this_indd_jpeg` is a member of a list generated with `set indd_jpeg_list to (every file of (export_path as alias) whose name begins with "page" and name ends with ".jpg")`.